# What is the equation the edge points on a quadrant on a circle in HTML5?

Tags: math

I am attempting to animate a spotlight in HTML5 canvas. What I want it to look like is this:
[image: points on a circle]

I am stuck on finding the two points in red. Quite naively,  I thought the equation for one of the points would be:

`x = circleOrigin.x + circle.radius/2;`
`y = circleOrigin.y + circle.radius/2;`

But when I move the circle around, the lines overlap the circle. Is there a better equation for these points?

Comment: How are you moving the spotlight? A rotate transformation could make your code more readable and easy to write.

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5, or Javascript? It's _just_ maths.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit , you raise a good point. This should probably be in Math Stack Exchange or something O_O

Comment: @Slamice: Bang on. :) Break down your problems into their most basic components, abstracting away irrelevant technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought one of the answers was correct but not verbose enough:

Finding the length between the points:

`var len = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.x - origin.x, 2) + Math.pow(circle.y - origin.y, 2));`

The point intersections:
`var intersectx = circle.x + (radius*(origin.y - circle.y)/len);`
`var intersecty = circle.y + (radius*(circle.x - origin.x)/len);`

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively straightforward geometry.  You're looking to form a tangent to the circle; therefore you're forming a right-angled triangle consisting of the origin, the centre of the circle, and the intersection with the circumference.  You know the lengths of two of the sides of this triangle (the radius, and the distance from the origin), so some basic trigonometry should give you the coordinates of the intersect point.